# Movie about possessed audio tape

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

In the early 90's I remember seeing parts of a movie about this record/tape that when people listened to it they become possessed/killed or something.

I only remember the one scene where a guy finds this girl in a car with headphones on and she was passed out. When he removed it there was this goo or slime on her ears.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add more detail and [edit] your question. As it stands, it is too broad; see [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) for information on how to ask story-identification questions.

Comment: Possibly [Ringu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178868/) (The Ring), but it's a video tape, and I haven't seen it, so I don't know about the car scene.

Comment: It does seem familiar (audio tape, specifically, not video tape.) I'm thinking maybe an episode of the X-Files, or something similar.  I can't find a good match right now, though.

Comment: @Steve-O A couple of similar things I remember: An episode of the cancelled NBC show Constantine, "The Devil's Vinyl", had a possessed record that killed whoever listened. The X-Files S10 episode "Founder's Mutation" had a scientist kill himself after hearing a high-pitched noise. Neither of those had green slime and both are more recent.

Answer (score 2):

It's not as far back as the early 90's, but it seems to have some similarities with the early 2000's TV series "Threshold"

The series stars Carla Gugino as Dr. Molly Caffrey, a high-level government crisis management consultant from the Blackwood Institute whose job is to create contingency plans for use in emergencies ranging from natural disasters to nuclear war. In order to have "all bases covered", one of her plans, code-named Threshold, is developed for dealing with the unlikely eventuality of first contact with aliens. One night, the crew of a U.S. naval vessel encounters a UFO. Many crew members subsequently die horribly, but some escape. After the ship is discovered with dead crew members and a videotape of the encounter, the Threshold protocol is activated.

Threshold learns that the aliens are attempting to rewrite the DNA of the human race using, in part, an audio signal that somehow alters some people's body chemistry in such a way that they become alien themselves. Central to all this is a fractal triskelion pattern that keeps appearing – in electronic signals, blood, and even the pattern made by city lights.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_(TV_series)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the movie [*Trick or Treat*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092112/), from 1986. A bullied kid finds a record from the dead musician Sammi Curr and playing it can cause demonic things to happen. The scene you are talking about is about 40 minutes in.

[image: Image from the film of young girl killed through her headphones]

Comment: A film largely remembered for cameos from Ozzy Osbourne and Gene Simmons (the latter featured on the box art). And very different from the, in my opinion superior, *Trick 'R Treat*.